# Hola, he creado un codigo para una tarea en netbeans, el problema es que al devolver los datos, estos se juntan en una sola linea

Tags: java, netbeans

```
public class EJERCICIO1 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Definir variables
        int MAT, SEM ;
        double PROM ;
        String CARR;
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in) ;
        Scanner teclado=new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Pedir datos
        System.out.println("Ingrese su matricula");
        System.out.println("Ingrese su carrera");
        System.out.println("Ingrese su semestre");
        System.out.println("Ingrese su promedio");
        System.out.println("Se determinará si es apto para pertenecer a "
                + "alguna de las facultades menores que tiene la universidad");
        //Leyendo eleccion
        MAT=leer.nextInt(); 
        CARR=teclado.nextLine();
        SEM=leer.nextInt();
        PROM=leer.nextDouble();
                        
        //Calculos y resultados
        if (SEM>6 && PROM>8.8) {
            System.out.println("Puede ser aceptado en Economia");
            System.out.println("Aqui estan sus datos ");            
                System.out.print(SEM);
                System.out.print(CARR);
                System.out.print(MAT);
                System.out.print(PROM);
        }
        if (SEM>6 && PROM>8.5 && PROM<8.8) {
            System.out.println("Puede ser aceptado en Computación");
            System.out.println("Aqui estan sus datos ");            
                System.out.print(SEM);
                System.out.print(CARR);
                System.out.print(MAT);
                System.out.print(PROM);
           
        }
        if (SEM>5 && PROM>8.5 && SEM<6) {
            System.out.println("Puede ser aceptado en Administración");
            System.out.println("Aqui estan sus datos ");            
                System.out.print(SEM);
                System.out.print(CARR);
                System.out.print(MAT);
                System.out.print(PROM);
           
        }
        if (SEM>5 && PROM>8.5 && SEM<6) {
            System.out.println("Puede ser aceptado en Contabilidad");
            System.out.println("Aqui estan sus datos ");            
                System.out.print(SEM);
                System.out.print(CARR);
                System.out.print(MAT);
                System.out.print(PROM);
           
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

Al imprimir los datos de vuelta, estos aparecen en una sola linea y juntos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en la mitad de tu codigo, usaste println... en la otra mitad, print... chequea la documentacion para entender la diferencia ;)

Comment: ya intentaste reemplazar print por println?

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.print` no añade un salto de linea al final. Puedes simplemente sustituirlos por `println` o puedes añadir manualmente los saltos de línea:

```java
System.out.print(SEM + "\n" + CARR + "\n" + MAT + "\n" + PROM + "\n");
```

o

```java
System.out.println(SEM);
System.out.println(CARR);
System.out.println(MAT);
System.out.println(PROM);
```